# scheduled task log to a file named after current date

Tags: date, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, logging

i have a scheduled task running for every 30 mins in ubuntu. i'm writing the log to a file called sh_tsk.log and using `>>` so that it doesn't overwrite. But what i want is to separate logs using dates. i.e today's log should be in a file named after today's date and tomorrow's log should be in a file named after tomorrow's date. i know i can use `touch` keyword to create a file. But what i don't know is how do i create the file using current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date` command:

```
touch `date +%Y%m%d`
```

Comment: thank you.. got it. i'm using like this though date +%d%m%Y :P

Comment: with %Y%m%d you'll get log files sorted in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$> touch `date +%F`.log
```

You should be getting the file as `2009-11-23.log`. Now you can use >> to output to this log file.